# Получение и изменение элемента html с помощью jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, smarty

Задача такая: нужно удалить содержимое тега "href" указанному на скрине элементу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Он всегда(!) является последним элементом в подобной вложенности.
Возможно, может можно как-то получить его и изменить с помощью его css свойств?..
З.Ы. подрабатываю на древнем проекте, разрешены самопал и костыли, здесь используется smarty, как сказал мне netbeans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#breadcrumbs span:last-of-type a').attr('href', '')
```

Comment: `breadcrumbs` это `id`

Comment: черт возьми, не знал, что здесь можно применять css-селекторы.

Comment: @Grundy fixed, thx

Comment: Grundy, рад вас здесь видеть, опять (:

Comment: lexxl, ваш ответ помог. строго и по делу! спасибо, жаль, но я не могу как-то поднять Вам рейтинг. извиняюсь.

Answer (score 1):

ну так измените атрибут элемента.

```
$("#тут элемент").attr("href","new url");
```